# Find the distance between HTML element and browser (or window) sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, distance

How to find the distance in pixels between html element and one of the browser (or window) sides (left or top) using jQuery?

Comment: Also see: [Measure distance between two HTML elements' centers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17628456/31671).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function for that. It gives you the element's position relative to the (left,top) of the *document*:

```
var offset = $("#target").offset();
display("span is at " + offset.left + "," + offset.top + 
  " of document");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/oveju4) On my browser, that example says that the span we've targeted is at 157,47 (left,top) of the document. This is because I've applied a big padding value to the `body` element, and used a span with a spacer above it and some text in front of it.

[Here's a second example](http://jsbin.com/oveju4/2) showing a paragraph at the absolute left,top of the document, showing 0,0 as its position (and also showing a span later on that's offset from both the left and top, 129,19 on my browser).

Answer (score 33):

[`jQuery.offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) needs to be combined with [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and [`scrollLeft`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) as shown in this diagram:

[image: viewport scroll and element offset]

Demo:

```js
function getViewportOffset($e) {
  var $window = $(window),
    scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft(),
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
    offset = $e.offset();
  return {
    left: offset.left - scrollLeft,
    top: offset.top - scrollTop
  };
}
$(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
  var viewportOffset = getViewportOffset($("#element"));
  $("#log").text("left: " + viewportOffset.left + ", top: " + viewportOffset.top);
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 1600px; height: 2048px; background-color: #CCCCCC; }
#element { width: 384px; height: 384px; margin-top: 1088px; margin-left: 768px; background-color: #99CCFF; }
#log { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; font: medium monospace; background-color: #EEE8AA; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- scroll right and bottom to locate the blue square -->
<div id="element"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```