# $(document).scrollTop() always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I'm simply trying to do something once the scroll position of the page reaches a certain height. However `scrollTop()` is returning 0 or `null` no matter how far down I scroll. This is the help function I'm using to check the `scrollTop()` value:

```
$('body').click(function(){
    var scrollPost = $(document).scrollTop();
    alert(scrollPost);
});
```

I've tried attaching `scrollTop()` to `$('body')`, `$('html')` and of course `$(window)`, but nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not an answer, but a side note...I usually use the jQuery waypoints plugin for things like this. http://getkickstrap.com/apps/waypoints-987090/

Comment: I really don't want to use a script to replace an extremely basic javascript function.

Comment: Your code works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/ZA7Uj/

Comment: It's working in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnDtj/) with Firefox

Comment: That's why this is so frustrating - there isn't much variation that can mess up this code. It's rock solid and yet doesn't work!

Comment: @jetlej some information on your environment may help. It seems that your code works for some (me included - Chrome on OS X). What OS/browser are you working with?

Comment: Try to make a minimal example. If you can't make it from bottom, try to remove all that you can remove from your page until you don't have the bug anymore. And of course debut to see what happens in the `var scro...` line.

Comment: There are also other ways to detect distance from top, [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4601868/1267663). Just in case.

Comment: @Whymarrh - I'm also using Chrome on OSX. I've also tried this out in FF and Safari

Comment: @jetlej I hate to ask, but does your page have enough content to scroll? Maybe the distance from top *is* 0.

Comment: @Whymarrh - Yes it has enough :)

Comment: That's wierd. Above, @dystroy has a working version. [It works for me, and here's what I'm running.](http://supportdetails.com/export.csv?bt=Chrome&bv=22.0.1229.79&je=1&ce=1&cd=24&rs=1440%20x%20900&bs=1440%20x%20714&fv=11.4.402&fvf=11.4.402)

Comment: Yup I know. That fiddle works for me in Safari, but the exact function on my site returns 0 every time.

Comment: @jetlej: *"but the exact function on my site returns 0 every time"*. In this case your site doesn't provide the exact same environment for this function. Please provide either a link to your site, or a lot more code.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

For some reason, removing 'height: 100%' from my html and body tags fixed this issue.

Comment: The easy solution to this problem is to set max-height on body and html instead of height.

Comment: This is caused by a bug in Chrome that is due to be fixed very soon: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157855

Comment: For those of us not using jQuery, my recommendation is to use `window.scrollY` instead.

Comment: just a side note;  I've found the `scrollTop()` to be inconsistent across browsers, and can be plauged with layout of the html.  It seems your 100% height is probably because an element inside your `BODY` tag was scrolling, and not the `BODY` tag itself.  So once you made your body full height, scrolling happened on that, which then made your `scrollTop` used.

Comment: what did you set it to? for me `body` is set to `height: auto` which i believe is also messing it up :/

Comment: "This is caused by a bug in Chrome that is due to be fixed very soon:" 
2023 reporting in, still not fixed

Answer (score 54):

I had same problem with scroll = 0 in:

```
document.body.scrollTop
```

Next time use

```
document.scrollingElement.scrollTop
```

Edit 01.06.2018

If you using `event` then you got object which has `document` element in `target` or `srcElement`. [image: Example] Here is a table showing scroll operation on different browsers.

[image]

As you can see Firefox and IE doesn't have `srcElement` and IE 11 doesn't support `scrollingElement`.

Comment: is `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop` mobile friendly?!

Comment: I don't know, now i'm using `documentElement` instead
`scrollingElement` and it works ;)

Comment: i'm having such issues implementing this feature again. i've done it in the past successfully and now i'm running into so many complications. would you mind taking a look at [this question that i posted to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323483/scrolling-progress-bar/50324136#50324136) to see if you can see anything wrong with what i'm doing?

Answer (score 9):

My solution, after trying some of the above and which doesn't involve changing any CSS:

```
var scroll_top = Math.max( $("html").scrollTop(), $("body").scrollTop() )
```

This works in up-to-date versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge.

Comment: `html`'s scrolltop worked for me. Nothing else did, even `body`'s. I am also using Bootstrap 4, though, and I have no idea what it's doing to the page behind the scenes.

Comment: OP is concerned about child elements rather than `html` or `body`/

Answer (score 6):

I just have an add-on for those who might make the same mistake as I did. My code was as followed:

```
var p = $('html,body');
$( ".info" ).text( "scrollTop:" + p.scrollTop() );
```

This code will work on all browser except for webkits browser such as chrome and safari  because the `<html>` tag always has a scrollTop value of zero or null.

The other browsers ignore it while webkit's browsers don't.

The simplest solutution is just to remove the html tag from your code et Voila:

```
var p = $('body');
$( ".info" ).text( "scrollTop:" + p.scrollTop() );
```

Answer (score 6):

Removing `height: 100%;` from html and body tags can resolve the issue.

The reason is that you might have set 100% as value of height property of html and body elements. If you set the height property of html and body elements to 100%, they get height equal to document’s height.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: And the page is down again.

Comment: @sp00n I'm going to remove the link. The necessary information of that page is already written here.

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem.
scrollTop() works with some block not document or body.
To make this method work u should add height and overflow style for your block:

```
#scrollParag {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And then:

```
var scrolParag = document.getElementById('scrollParag');
 alert(scrolParag.scrollTop); // works!
```

Answer (score 1):

Scroll Top was always returning 0 for me as well. I was using it for bringing focus to the specific element on a page. I used another approach to do so.

document.getElementById("elementID").scrollIntoView();

Working well for me on mobile, tablet, and desktop.

Comment: Is that really a function?

Answer (score 1):

```
var bodyScrollTop = Math.max(document.scrollingElement.scrollTop, document.documentElement.scrollTop)
```

should work on modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, it seems that you should use

```
$("body").scrollTop()
```

instead of

```
$(".some-class").scrollTop
```

This is why I am stuck.