# html scrolltop mystery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I am building a web editor. when large elements are added to the editor,  the page appears to scroll down, causing the menu at the top to scroll out of view. 
As a test, I am running the function below on the entire document - but none have scrolltop other than zero (unless I deliberately increase the contents of some container to test). please note that body and html tags have height set to 100%.

related: [$(document).scrollTop() always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788487/document-scrolltop-always-returns-0)

```
  ScrollCheck : function (contextSelector){
    var scrollTop = 0;
    $(contextSelector).find('*').each(function () {
        scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
       // scrollTop = $(this).offset().top;

       if (scrollTop != 0) {
            console.log(scrollTop, $(this));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS related to this problem.  My thinking is that it may be a CSS issue.  Your scroll DIV may have a bigger height than the viewable container, but its just a guess without seeing your code.

Comment: The code is large, complex, and not yet publicly accessible on production servers. I will try now to replicate the issue with simpler components.

Comment: body, html { width:100%; height:100%; max-width:100%; max-height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; position:fixed;}   I have some wrappers with display inline-block - perhaps a vertical text alignment issue is the cause

Comment: Try using http://jsfiddle.net to replicate the problem.  The code you posted was just the CSS and that really doesn't help much.  Need to see the HTML and CSS in action.

Comment: I created a trimmed down version of the site- with all the css and html- but almost none of the scripts. the problem was not replicated there. going back to the original application: I removed the containment parameter from jquery ui draggable on newly added elements. now the problem is not reproduced. apparently, something in the jquery ui code is contributing to this unwanted behavior. fortunately, updates to the specification call for removing the containment boundaries - so its now a non-issue :)