# jQuery matchHeight maintainScroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using jQuery [matchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) for a few elements on my site. I can trigger an update if needed by firing:

```
$.fn.matchHeight._update();
```

My problem is that I loose scroll position. There is `$.fn.matchHeight._maintainScroll = true;` which I have set at the top of the function where I'm calling matchHeight into play. And hooked into my Slider onChange function I've got an update, like so;

```
$('#reviews-slider').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        nav: false,
        lazyLoad : true,
        items: 1,
        dots: true,
        autoHeight:true,
        itemElement: 'blockquote',
        dotsSpeed: 400,
        autoplay: false,
        onChanged : function () {
            $.fn.matchHeight._update();
        }
    });
```

Does anyone kno what I'm doing wrong and why my maintain scroll doesn't seem to be working. Can it be called in along with `_update`? I did try putting it within the change function, however this still didn't work.

The reason I'm looking to use maintain scroll is due to the fact when I trigger an update, the content can be considerably longer and cause a jump in page position. There is a note at the bottom of the git page for this, however I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem after an ajax call my page jumped up.
The option `_maintainScrollPosition` seems to be taken into account but `$(window).scrollTop()` is always 0 in webkit browsers due to a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788487/document-scrolltop-always-returns-0) or "featured bug".

The library code that causes this issue:

```
// take note of scroll position
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(), // seems to be 0 most of the time 

// ***

// restore scroll position if enabled
if (matchHeight._maintainScroll) {
    $(window).scrollTop((scrollTop / htmlHeight) * $('html').outerHeight(true));
}
```

We all know how multiplying by 0 looks like.

**The solution**

Unfortunately it's a drastic CSS change where you would remove `height: 100%` from the html and body tag. 
Also `overflow: hidden` on the body will fail when you're dealing with overflow containers for example.