# Detect body scroll offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to put the scrolling behaviour on the body rather than the HTML, due to using CSS Parallax. However, I have got an issue with adding sticky classes to my header using JavaScript.

I need to be able to detect that the body has scrolled, this works fine, however i'm unable to get the offset that the user has scrolled to!

I have tried everything when is online, for example:

```
$('body').scrollTop()
document.body.scrollTop
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].pageYOffset
```

None of this is working, it always returns **0**!

**Edit:**

I can't modify any of the HTML apart from what is between the comments.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AutoDealer">
      <div id="main-wrap" class="parallax">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="main twelvecol">

            <!-- Editable -->
            <div>
              <div class="row-block finance parallax__group">
                <div class="parallax__layer--back parallax__layer"></div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="parallax__layer--base parallax__layer">
                      <p>This is all of the top level content</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Editable -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is a codepen showing the various examples not working
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgPrQv

Comment: Have you tried getting `document.body.scrollHeight`? Or `.offset().top`?

Comment: `document.body.scrollHeight` just returns the height of the document

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: document.body.offset is not a function`

Comment: Pretty sure this is a known bug for Webkit. I can get a scroll position in Firefox just fine, but not in Chrome. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788487/document-scrolltop-always-returns-0. As suggested in that question, I could get a scroll position in Chrome if I removed your `html` styles, but that messes up the parallax effect, so not sure what the fix is in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

Comment: I'm not as the body is doing the scrolling, not the window.

Comment: There is no working example, that's the issue. See this codepen, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgPrQv - try and get the scroll offset of the body

Comment: @MartynBall can we have a outer div which wraps all of your html just inside `body`? You can get its offset