# Why is window.pageYOffset always 0? and how can I get a value to check if the page has being scrolled down or up?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I'm trying to hide an element on my ionic app when the app is scrolled down and show when the app is scrolled up.

I am doing this through a component so I can just put tags around whatever elements I want this functionality on.

I thought I would be able to get the value of `window.PageYOffset` when a scroll event fires but the `window.PageYOffset` value is always 0. I thought this value would relate to the number of pixels the document is scrolled along on the Y axis, but I obviously misunderstand something.

in my `hide-on-scroll` componenet I have

```
private eventOptions: boolean|{capture?: boolean, passive?: boolean};
ngAfterViewInit(){

    //removed where I set eventOptions

  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, <any>this.eventOptions);
  });

  }
  scroll = (event: any): void => {
    var a = window.pageYOffset; //value is always 0
  };
```

this fires on every scroll movement

**my HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <hide-on-scroll>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </hide-on-scroll>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="page-background">
  <div *ngIf="margins">
    <div *ngFor="let val of margins.ByZone">
      <div style="height:500px; margin-top:20px">
        <h1>dummy content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**Two questions**

Why is window.pageYOffset always 0?

In my scroll event how can I get a value to check if the page has being scrolled down or up?

**Update**

ionic is auto generating `<html>` and `<body>` tags and is setting a `height:100%` value in them. Joel Joseph mentioned in the comments that this is a problem when trying to  get `window.PageYOffset` . Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: this may help you : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-sticky-header-on-scroll/

Comment: Hi @JoelJoseph thanks for the link, its very clear and informative but it does not help me understand why `window.pageYOffset;` is always 0 in my attempt

Comment: check if `overflow-x: hidden` inside the body  or something related to setting `height:100%` there was this weird  problem when i have worked on this article

Comment: I did not not set `overflow-x` but I tried setting it and `overflow-y` to every combination and it made no difference

Comment: from what i know you should not be setting `overflow-x: hidden` inside the body or  should not set `height:100%` . This was what that solved my issue . Did you inspect document elements in chrome console to see if it has been set , if yes you should remove it

Comment: check this thread , it has similar discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788487/document-scrolltop-always-returns-0

Comment: ionic is auto setting `height:100%` on body and html, is there a way around this?  (thank you for all the time you have taken)

Comment: pageYOffset is always 0 as technically in Ionic you are not scrolling the document. You are scrolling overflow inside of ion-content.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is using `window.pageYOffset` and the scroll event with `ion-content`. You will need to use the scrolling events ionic provides thats part of [ion-content](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content)

```
<ion-content class="page-background" [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScrollStart)="onIonScrollEnd($event)">
  <div *ngIf="margins">
    <div *ngFor="let val of margins.ByZone">
      <div style="height:500px; margin-top:20px">
        <h1>dummy content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>


onIonScrollEnd(event) {
    console.log(event)
}
```

be sure to turn on scrolling events with `scrollEvents` too

as far as getting the YOffset while using `ion-content` I wish I knew, im trying to hunt down a good solution for that as well